# Как достать массив из объекта, который я получил после парсинга JSON

Tags: json, swift

Я изучаю IOS и делаю свое первое приложение, работающее с API.

После запроса я получают JSON файл. Ниже небольшая вырезка из файла

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "totalResults": 2,
  "articles": [
    {
      "source": {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "someName"
      },
      "author": "David Waterworth",
      "title": "ValidBook",
      "url": "https://validbooksomehere.com/",
      "urlToImage": "https://validbooksomehere.com/image",
      "publishedAt": "2021-11-20T00:23:40Z",
      "content": "about more"
    },
{ … },
]
}
```

MARK - Это просто пример

Я декодирую полученные данные, код ниже

```
struct NewsDataModel: Codable {
    let status: String
    let totalResults: Int
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
    let source: Source
    let author: String?
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let url: String
    let urlToImage: String?
    let publishedAt: Date
    let content: String?
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String
}
```

И вот тут появился такой момент. По итогу мне нужно получить массив из элементов:
`author` `title` `url` `urlToImage`
Если посмотреть на JSON структуру, то все они находятся в массиве по ключу `articles`, то есть, каждый элемент массива `articles`

Вот модель, которую мне нужно получить, чтоб заполнить View в моем проекте

```
struct NewsModel {
    let newsTitle: String
    let urlToNewsWebSite: String?
    let authorWebSiteName: String
    let urlToImage: String
    
    init(newsData: NewsDataModel) {
      // Как?!
    }
}
```

Как мне в итоге получить массив объектов типа NewsModel, если я получаю единичный элемент, который в себе содержит массив объектов, которые в итоге мне нужно разложить по этой модели?

MARK - Это моей первый проект, до этого казалось все логичным и понятным, но этот момент просто выбил из колеи, первое что приходит в голову, как то использовать цикл, но как его правильно тут применить, придумать мне не удалось. Код ниже

```
init(newsData: NewsDataModel) {
    for article in newsData.articles {
        self.newsTitle = article.title
        self.urlToNewsWebSite = article.url
        self.authorWebSiteName = article.source.name
        self.urlToNewsWebSite = article.urlToImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно создать массив данных вне модели, init не нужен:

```
var newsArray = [NewsModel]()

for article in newsData.articles {
    let news = NewsModel(
        newsTitle: article.title,
        urlToNewsWebSite: article.url,
        authorWebSiteName: article.source.name,
        urlToImage: article.urlToImage)
    
    newsArray.append(news)
}
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, подскажите, где лучше вписать данный код? В контроллере? или в Network Manager? (Отдельный SWIFT файл по работе с сетью у меня создан)

Comment: Там, где вы будете использовать этот массив.